# Dual national UK and Australia

Tags: dual-nationality, australian-citizens

I am a dual national currently living in the UK and I hold UK and Australian passports. I am planning a holiday to Australia soon. However, my Australian passport is in my maiden name (UK passport in the married name).

Will I have problems getting into Australia? Can I apply for an e-visa on my UK passport, and just use this, or should I also take my Australian passport even although it's still in my maiden name?

Answer (score 3):

No there is no problem whatsoever with the name change. You’re still an Australian citizen and if you have any evidence to document the name change that will be helpful. But you do not need a visa at all.

Comment: Not only do they not need a visa, they are not eligible for one.

Comment: Make sure your use the name on your passport for your ticket.

Comment: some countries **require by law** to enter with their country's specific passport if exists regardless of other passports in possession - you should check that for Australia.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen In Australia, you "should" use an Australian passport, but there are no legal penalties.  However, in practice it's difficult to get to Oz without one, since Australian citizens are not eligible for Australian visas.

Answer (score 2):

some countries require by law to enter with their country's specific passport if exists regardless of other passports in possession.

This [Australian gov. dual national page](https://smartraveller.gov.au/guide/pages/dual-nationals.aspx) states :

> **Entering and leaving Australia**
>
> All Australians, including dual
> nationals, should leave and enter Australia on their Australian
> passport. If you have a passport from another country you can use that
> for travel once you have left Australia. People trying to enter
> Australia as an Australian citizen but without an Australian passport
> will face difficulties and delays.

and

> An Australian passport is the
> preferred and most conclusive proof of Australian citizenship when
> travelling. Dual nationals should use an Australian passport to enter
> and depart Australia.

As for your name - bring a proof of name change, but if you have registered as married in the Australian consulate ( as you should have in case of marital status change  ) then this should not be a problem, and further more - you can, if you wish apply for a free new passport due to name change as explained in [this page dedicated to passport related change of name](https://www.passports.gov.au/have-you-changed-your-name)

If you ...

> marry or enter a registered relationship overseas and wish to assume
> your partner’s family name or add it to your own

you should present

> an Australian RBDM name change certificate, because your marriage or
> entry into a relationship overseas cannot be registered by an
> Australian RBDM

( I actually admire how ordered and easy to find all that information is with a simple 2 sec. search - Kudos to the Australian related authorities .. )

And just as @ jcaron commented in other answer - your problem could be more with the airline than with the immigration officer in Australia and in fact the same above [dual nationals page](https://smartraveller.gov.au/guide/pages/dual-nationals.aspx#passports-and-visas) states ..

> International airlines have an obligation to carry only appropriately
> documented passengers to Australia. Appropriate documentation for
> Australian nationals is an Australian passport. Appropriate
> documentation for a foreign national is a visa to enter Australia. If
> an Australian national attempts to board a flight to Australia without
> an Australian passport, airlines will likely be unable to verify their
> claim to Australian citizenship at the time of check-in and may refuse
> boarding

In that regard I must say that I also posses multiple passports with different names ( similar case to yours ) and whenever a doubt arise with any particular officer ( may it be airline or immigration ) i just show either the other passport or a form from the consulate stating legal name change .